# Setting up an event trigger event from PostgreSQL to a Heroku-hosted Python script

Tags: python-3.x, asynchronous, polling, heroku-postgres

I am trying to figure out the best way to trigger a python script automatically once a new row is auto-added to a pSQL db. I'm considering creating a 'TRIGGER' in pSQL OR using some polling logic (no xp doing this) in the .py script to constantly check the db for changes. My concern is that polling may be resource intensive and not sure how efficient it'd be for handling async tasks. E.g. 3 new rows get added to the db at the same time.

Does anyone have an example / insights to an effective way of doing this? Context on the use case below:

A user completes a typeform, a new row is auto-added to a pSQL db upon submission. (All good up until here) I then need to trigger a python script hosted in Heroku to fetch that new row from the db, do some stuff and fire off an email (SendGrid API) to the user with some cool insights. Thanks in advance!

(NOTE - I'm not hard set on Heroku at all, any cloud db can work, just mentioning this as someone may know of some cool client-side / no-code features that can be setup for the db related to polling)

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a great use case for Webhooks.

If you are not familiar with Webhooks, it's a way to be notified in real-time when something happens in a platform on the URL of your choice. In this case, when someone submits a Typeform, you will receive on your server a JSON payload containing all the answers that were submitted.

Once the payload received on your side you can do both: store the answer in the database and call the Sendgrid API.

Here is an example of the payload:

```
{
    "event_id": "LtWXD3crgy",
    "event_type": "form_response",
    "form_response": {
        "form_id": "lT4Z3j",
        "token": "a3a12ec67a1365927098a606107fac15",
        "submitted_at": "2018-01-18T18:17:02Z",
        "landed_at": "2018-01-18T18:07:02Z",
        "calculated": {
            "score": 9
        },
        "definition": {
            "id": "lT4Z3j",
            "title": "Webhooks example",
            "fields": [
                {
                    "id": "DlXFaesGBpoF",
                    "title": "Thanks, {{answer_60906475}}! What's it like where you live? Tell us in a few sentences.",
                    "type": "long_text",
                    "ref": "[readable_ref_long_text",
                    "allow_multiple_selections": false,
                    "allow_other_choice": false
                },
                {
                    "id": "SMEUb7VJz92Q",
                    "title": "If you're OK with our city management following up if they have further questions, please give us your email address.",
                    "type": "email",
                    "ref": "readable_ref_email",
                    "allow_multiple_selections": false,
                    "allow_other_choice": false
                },
                {
                    "id": "JwWggjAKtOkA",
                    "title": "What is your first name?",
                    "type": "short_text",
                    "ref": "readable_ref_short_text",
                    "allow_multiple_selections": false,
                    "allow_other_choice": false
                },
                {
                    "id": "KoJxDM3c6x8h",
                    "title": "When did you move to the place where you live?",
                    "type": "date",
                    "ref": "readable_ref_date",
                    "allow_multiple_selections": false,
                    "allow_other_choice": false
                },
                {
                    "id": "PNe8ZKBK8C2Q",
                    "title": "Which pictures do you like? You can choose as many as you like.",
                    "type": "picture_choice",
                    "ref": "readable_ref_picture_choice",
                    "allow_multiple_selections": true,
                    "allow_other_choice": false
                },
                {
                    "id": "Q7M2XAwY04dW",
                    "title": "On a scale of 1 to 5, what rating would you give the weather in Sydney? 1 is poor weather, 5 is excellent weather",
                    "type": "number",
                    "ref": "readable_ref_number1",
                    "allow_multiple_selections": false,
                    "allow_other_choice": false
                },
                {
                    "id": "gFFf3xAkJKsr",
                    "title": "By submitting this form, you understand and accept that we will share your answers with city management. Your answers will be anonymous will not be shared.",
                    "type": "legal",
                    "ref": "readable_ref_legal",
                    "allow_multiple_selections": false,
                    "allow_other_choice": false
                },
                {
                    "id": "k6TP9oLGgHjl",
                    "title": "Which of these cities is your favorite?",
                    "type": "multiple_choice",
                    "ref": "readable_ref_multiple_choice",
                    "allow_multiple_selections": false,
                    "allow_other_choice": false
                },
                {
                    "id": "RUqkXSeXBXSd",
                    "title": "Do you have a favorite city we haven't listed?",
                    "type": "yes_no",
                    "ref": "readable_ref_yes_no",
                    "allow_multiple_selections": false,
                    "allow_other_choice": false
                },
                {
                    "id": "NRsxU591jIW9",
                    "title": "How important is the weather to your opinion about a city? 1 is not important, 5 is very important.",
                    "type": "opinion_scale",
                    "ref": "readable_ref_opinion_scale",
                    "allow_multiple_selections": false,
                    "allow_other_choice": false
                },
                {
                    "id": "WOTdC00F8A3h",
                    "title": "How would you rate the weather where you currently live? 1 is poor weather, 5 is excellent weather.",
                    "type": "rating",
                    "ref": "readable_ref_rating",
                    "allow_multiple_selections": false,
                    "allow_other_choice": false
                },
                {
                    "id": "pn48RmPazVdM",
                    "title": "On a scale of 1 to 5, what rating would you give the general quality of life in Sydney? 1 is poor, 5 is excellent",
                    "type": "number",
                    "ref": "readable_ref_number2",
                    "allow_multiple_selections": false,
                    "allow_other_choice": false
                }
            ]
        },
        "answers": [
            {
                "type": "text",
                "text": "It's cold right now! I live in an older medium-sized city with a university. Geographically, the area is hilly.",
                "field": {
                    "id": "DlXFaesGBpoF",
                    "type": "long_text"
                }
            },
            {
                "type": "email",
                "email": "laura@example.com",
                "field": {
                    "id": "SMEUb7VJz92Q",
                    "type": "email"
                }
            },
            {
                "type": "text",
                "text": "Laura",
                "field": {
                    "id": "JwWggjAKtOkA",
                    "type": "short_text"
                }
            },
            {
                "type": "date",
                "date": "2005-10-15",
                "field": {
                    "id": "KoJxDM3c6x8h",
                    "type": "date"
                }
            },
            {
                "type": "choices",
                "choices": {
                    "labels": [
                        "London",
                        "Sydney"
                    ]
                },
                "field": {
                    "id": "PNe8ZKBK8C2Q",
                    "type": "picture_choice"
                }
            },
            {
                "type": "number",
                "number": 5,
                "field": {
                    "id": "Q7M2XAwY04dW",
                    "type": "number"
                }
            },
            {
                "type": "boolean",
                "boolean": true,
                "field": {
                    "id": "gFFf3xAkJKsr",
                    "type": "legal"
                }
            },
            {
                "type": "choice",
                "choice": {
                    "label": "London"
                },
                "field": {
                    "id": "k6TP9oLGgHjl",
                    "type": "multiple_choice"
                }
            },
            {
                "type": "boolean",
                "boolean": false,
                "field": {
                    "id": "RUqkXSeXBXSd",
                    "type": "yes_no"
                }
            },
            {
                "type": "number",
                "number": 2,
                "field": {
                    "id": "NRsxU591jIW9",
                    "type": "opinion_scale"
                }
            },
            {
                "type": "number",
                "number": 3,
                "field": {
                    "id": "WOTdC00F8A3h",
                    "type": "rating"
                }
            },
            {
                "type": "number",
                "number": 4,
                "field": {
                    "id": "pn48RmPazVdM",
                    "type": "number"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Here is an example to handle the webhook payload: [https://glitch.com/~tf-webhook-receiver](https://glitch.com/%7Etf-webhook-receiver)

And [Typeform documentation](https://developer.typeform.com/webhooks/example-payload/).

Answer (score 0):

An easier approach will be to submit the form to a function of yours first which then handles **DB** storing of new data and email notification via **SendGrid**, instead of storing to DB first.

Typeform has [webhook functionality](https://developer.typeform.com/webhooks/) that you can use for that.

You configure it to send a newly filled form to a function of yours (hosted on Heroku or wherever in your case) then do whatever is necessary on that function.